# Python pandas tagging entries in dataframe shortening code

Tags: python, regex, pandas, iteration

So I am using python pandas have an the following variables:

- a dataframe `df` with a column 'TAG' I created to tag data into
  groups based on data from a column 'IDnumber'.
- regex patterns stored in arrays `pattern1`, `pattern2`,
  `pattern2-2`, ...etc
- an array `group` which is filled with strings (ie: 'software', 'engineering', 'marketing'...etc).

The code is filling in the column df.TAG with strings from the array `group` based on the regex patterns  `pattern1`, `pattern2`, `pattern22`, ...etc

So far I have working code but there is redundancy in having multiple for loops that look the same

```
for i in range(len(pattern1)):
    df.loc[df.IDnumber.str.contains(pattern1[i]) & (df.TAG == ''),'TAG'] = group[1]

for i in range(len(pattern2)):
    df.loc[df.IDnumber.str.contains(pattern2[i]) & (df.TAG == ''),'TAG'] = group[2]

for i in range(len(pattern22)):
    df.loc[df.IDnumber.str.contains(pattern22[i]) & (df.TAG == ''),'TAG'] = group[2]

for i in range(len(pattern33)):
    df.loc[df.IDnumber.str.contains(pattern33[i]) & (df.TAG == ''),'TAG'] = group[3]

for i in range(len(pattern3)):
    df.loc[df.IDnumber.str.contains(pattern3[i]) & (df.TAG == ''),'TAG'] = group[3]
```

I am also getting a warning.

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
  df.loc[df.IDnumber.str.contains(pattern1[i]),'TAG'] = group[1]
```

But the code works so I would like to know if there is a way to make the code more efficient by reducing the number of for loops and remove the warning without using `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None` to suppress the warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first for-loop:

```
for i in range(len(pattern1)):
    df.loc[df.IDnumber.str.contains(pattern1[i]) & (df.TAG == ''),'TAG'] = group[1]
```

can be replaced with

```
empty = (df.TAG == '')
mask = df.IDnumber.str.contains('|'.join(pattern1)) & empty
df.loc[mask, 'TAG'] = group[1]
```

This might be faster, since the entire loop is being replaced with one regex pattern. A similar refactoring can be done for your second and last `for-loops`.

But your third and fourth `for-loops` perplex me: `for i in range(len(pattern2-2)):`. Python names can not contain hyphens. So what does `pattern2-2` mean? If `pattern2-2` is just another array of strings (albeit with an invalid variable name!?) then your third and fourth loops can be handled the same as shown above.

---

If all the patterns are simply arrays of strings, then you could refactor all the for-loops with something like

```
import itertools as IT
patterns = [pattern1, pattern2, pattern3, pattern4, pattern5]
empty = (df.TAG == '')
for pattern, grp in IT.izip(patterns, group):
    mask = df.IDnumber.str.contains('|'.join(pattern)) & empty
    df.loc[mask, 'TAG'] = grp
```

Note that whenever you have numbered variable names, such as `pattern1`, `pattern2`, etc. it is usually a sign that theses variables should be replaced by a single variable which is a list or tuple, such as `patterns` above. Then instead of referencing `pattern1`, you'd simply use `patterns[0]`.

Comment: oops the dash was accidentally added

Comment: not sure but it looks like your code would tag everything as `group[1]`

Comment: `for pattern, grp in IT.izip(patterns, group)` will make `grp` step through the values in `group`.